# JVM crashes when running SOAPUI on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jvm, soapui

I just downloaded SOAPUI 4.0.1 and tried to run it in Ubuntu 11.10.  I run the file soapui.sh.  The application started up and the window actually appeared, but then after a few seconds it closed.  Looking at the terminal I saw that the JVM crashed.  Below are the details of the error:

```
(process:4183): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.30.0/./gobject/gtype.c:2708: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:4183): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed

(process:4183): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

Problematic frame:
C  [libgconf-2.so.4+0x15b99]  gconf_enum_to_string+0xd59
```

Can anyone help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Look here: http://www.eviware.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=7736

Look in ..../soapui-4.0.1/bin/soapui.sh:

```
#uncomment to disable browser component
#JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dsoapui.jxbrowser.disable=true" <- uncomment this line
```

if you are usising soapui.sh to start soapUI. If you used installer and using launcher than
in soapUI-*.vmoptions add -Dsoapui.jxbrowser.disable=true

that should do the trick.

Comment: if you still get core dumps try running soapui from its home directory  http://www.eviware.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=7736#p29854

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue

```
--
DUMP
...
# JRE version: 6.0_33-b03
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (20.8-b03 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgconf-2.so.4+0x176aa]  __float128+0x176aa
...
OS:Fedora release 16 (Verne)
uname:Linux 3.3.2-6.fc16.i686 #1 SMP Sat Apr 21 13:23:12 UTC 2012 i686
libc:glibc 2.14.90 NPTL 2.14.90 
...
--
```

This jxbrowser...jar is working with xulrunner-2.8...jar and native code doesn't full compatible with your OS dependencies.

jxbrowser it's used for 'HTML rendering' but works also without it.

--
It works also in FC16